# Piramide 3D con CSS

Tags: css, css3

Necesito crear esta figura con CSS. Teniendo en cuenta que deben ser 3 elementos diferentes para poder trabajar sobre cada uno independientemente. Tengo conocimientos para crear un trangulo pero estoy estancado en como unir los 3 que necesito.

```
<div class="triangle"></div>    

.triangle{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 0 176px 217px 0;
  border-color: transparent #FF0000 transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(24deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(24deg);
  transform: rotate(24deg);
}
```

Alguna idea? Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: las preguntas deben iniciar mostrando lo que haz intentado para que tengan buen recibimiento por parte de la comunidad y apoyar en dudas puntuales

Comment: Listo, ya aclare que no tengo problemas de armar triangulos pero no puedo unirlos como una piramide. Gracias

Comment: Aquí tienes un enlace a un artículo donde explica detalladamente el proceso de crear una pirámide con CSS3 y SASS: http://www.thesoftwaresimpleton.com/blog/2016/06/28/pyramid/ Además, en el artículo utiliza animación en CSS para rotar la pirámide. Espero que te sirva.